How do you modify a Couchbase record that contains a fairly complex object and sub-object?
I have a couchbase database full of records that look like this:
{
  "_class": "com.discussoftware.server.shared.model.bo.licenseBo",
  "customerId": "A1A2",
  "term": "SUBSCRIPTION",
  "keys": {
    "abc-123-evaluation": {
      "active": true,
      "expirationDate": 1669680000000,
      "key": "abc-123-evaluation",
      "name": "base product, floating, subscription",
      "notBefore": 1667088000000,
      "options": [
        {
          "option": "base",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "option": "secondary",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "option": "teriary",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "option": "ops",
          "quantity": 1
        }
      ],
      "units": 1,
      "version": 
       {
    "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "patch": 0 
       }    
    }
  },
  "master": "def-456",
  "productId": "a1a2a3a4",
  "supportId": "A1A2A3"
}

I can select based on the license key, with a statement like this:
SELECT  *
FROM server1` AS d
WHERE ANY v in OBJECT_VALUES(d.keys) 
   SATISFIES v.expirationDate < 1713744000000 
     AND v.expirationDate > 1701734400000
     AND v.version.major == 1
     AND v.version.minor == 1
     AND v.version.patch == 0
   END;

But what I am having trouble with a writing an UPDATE that will let me update the version value.
I think the best one I have tried -- which returns 0 rows -- out of the 60 or so attempts, has been:
UPDATE `server1` AS d 
SET v.version = {"major": 2, "minor": 1, "batch": = 0}
WHERE ANY v in OBJECT_VALUES(d.keys)
  SATISFIES v.expirationDate < 1713744000000
     AND v.expirationDate > 1701734400000
     AND v.version.major == 1
     AND v.version.minor == 1
     AND v.version.patch == 0
  END;


It seems like you have an answer, if that query works. What's not working how you expect?

The Update query doesn't work, it returns no rows, even though the select returns rows

This works - but you'll need to hard-code and execute for all the values of abc-123-evaluation.
UPDATE `travel-sample` AS d 
    SET d.`keys`.`abc-123-evaluation`.version = {"major": 2, "minor": 1, "patch": 0}
    WHERE
    d.`keys`.`abc-123-evaluation`.expirationDate > 1669670000000 AND
    d.`keys`.`abc-123-evaluation`.expirationDate < 1713744000000 AND
    d.`keys`.`abc-123-evaluation`.version.major == 1 AND
    d.`keys`.`abc-123-evaluation`.version.minor == 1 AND
    d.`keys`.`abc-123-evaluation`.version.patch == 0
      returning d

The predicate is indeed finding the documents, the issue is that the SET is (apparently) setting the values on the (intermediate?) object v, and not on the document.
When I insert your sample document in my bucket,  make the changes below to your query, and run it, it returns 1 mutation.  But when I fetch look at the document in couchbase, it is not changed. I assume that n1ql makes a temporary object v and updates that. Which is not helpful.
(1) keys needs to be in back-ticks, it's a reserved word.  (2) remove the extraneous '=' in '"batch": = 0', and change name from batch to patch; (3) change the second(lower) date in the query so it is less than the one in the sample (4) remove OBJECT_VALUES (curiously, it seems to work the same with or without OBJECT_VALUES) (5) add , d.updated=1 just to show that the document gets updated. (but v.version does not).
insert into `travel-sample` (key, value) values ("1", {
  "_class": "com.discussoftware.server.shared.model.bo.licenseBo",
  "customerId": "A1A2",
  "term": "SUBSCRIPTION",
  "keys": {
    "abc-123-evaluation": {
      "active": true,
      "expirationDate": 1669680000000,
      "key": "abc-123-evaluation",
      "name": "base product, floating, subscription",
      "notBefore": 1667088000000,
      "options": [
        {
          "option": "base",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "option": "secondary",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "option": "teriary",
          "quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "option": "ops",
          "quantity": 1
        }
      ],
      "units": 1,
      "version": 
       {
    "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "patch": 0 
       }    
    }
  },
  "master": "def-456",
  "productId": "a1a2a3a4",
  "supportId": "A1A2A3"
})

 UPDATE `travel-sample` AS d 
    SET v.version = {"major": 2, "minor": 1, "batch": 0}
    WHERE ANY v in d.`keys`
      SATISFIES v.expirationDate < 1713744000000
         AND v.expirationDate > 1669670000000 
         AND v.version.major == 1
         AND v.version.minor == 1
         AND v.version.patch == 0
      END;


 success just now  355.4ms  1 mutations


The simplest UPDATE that I could think of to write to update that field is:
UPDATE records._default._default 
USE KEYS "doc1"
SET `keys`.`abc-123-evaluation`.`version` = {"major":9, "minor":9, "patch":9}


That might work for one record.  My production db has 19,000 records and over 80 of them meet the select criteria to have their version updated.  It's frustrating to say the least.  Thanks for trying.

Sorry, I didn't read carefully enough.

No worries.  I am still looking.  I think part of the problem is how the 'keys' objects are defined.  Getting to the subobject is giving me issues.

UPDATE `server1` AS d
SET v1.version.major = v1.version.major+1
      FOR n:v1 IN d.`keys`
           WHEN v1.expirationDate < 1713744000000
                AND v1.expirationDate > 1701734400000
                AND v1.version.major == 1
                AND v1.version.minor == 1
                AND v1.version.patch == 0
     END
WHERE ANY v in OBJECT_VALUES(d.keys)
  SATISFIES v.expirationDate < 1713744000000
     AND v.expirationDate > 1701734400000
     AND v.version.major == 1
     AND v.version.minor == 1
     AND v.version.patch == 0
  END;

https://docs.couchbase.com/cloud/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html#update-for
